# Jetpack: Subscribe via e-mail

Tags: plugins, plugin-jetpack

I just updated to the latest Wordpress version and also updated Jetpack to the newest version.

There's a new feature that let's users subscribe via e-mail so they'll get an instant notification if there's a new blog post.
I always wanted a function like that, so I actived it.

However, I only need the widget function:
a widget in the sidebar with a small form to subscribe via e-mail

I don't want it in the comment form (below each post), because there I'm already a more advanced system for subscribing (subscribe to comments reloaded plugin).

I had a look at the Jetpack files, but they look so complicated that I don't dare to touch them (although I usually have no problem modifying plugin files).

I thought that maybe somebody else already tried what I want to do and can help me out?
If not, could you have a look at the file and let me know if it's possible to do it?
Let me know if you need the file (in case you're not using Jetpack).

EDIT: More information for hopefully better understanding

So, after installing Jetpack it automatically puts the option to subscribe to the comments below the comment form like this:

[image]

While the first 2 lines are from the Jetpack one, the latter one is from a plugin called "subscribe to comments reloaded".
I only want to use the latter one, not the one from Jetpack!

I can't disable it as there's another function that I want to keep!
That is a widget in the sidebar that lets you subscribe to immediate updates when a new post is published!

[image]

I suppose the only way to only keep the widget while turning off the thing in the comment form is to modify the Jetpack plugin php files. However, they're very complicated and I do not dare to tough them myself, so I was wondering if anybody else might know what to do!

[Here's](http://zoomingjapan.com/) my website for reference.
Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Comment: I would suggest trying the [JetPack Plugin support forum at wordpress.org](http://wordpress.org/tags/jetpack?forum_id=10).

Comment: Oh, there is such a thing? I tried to google it, but I couldn't find anything related. Thanks a lot for pointing it out!

Comment: All Plugins and Themes hosted at wordpress.org have dedicated support forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I only need the widget function: a widget in the sidebar with
>   a small form to subscribe via e-mail

There is a widget to do. On your site's widgets configuration page, search for "Blog Subscriptions (Jetpack)" and drag it to an active sidebar.

Comment: No, no. I'm using the widget. No issue with that. I only want to get rid of what's written below the comment form while still keeping the widget in the sidebar, but that doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: @japanworm Oh, ok. But, still bit confusing to guess what you describe. Can you please share your website URL? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I updated my question (please have a look at it), I hope it's clearer now, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You can uncheck the box using the options added for comments in JetPack.

[image]

Comment: Hello. This option wasn't available at the time of writing this question. However, even when I uncheck the boxes, it won't disappear in the actual post. I just can hope that this will be fixed in one of the future Jetpack updates.